# how to get dynamic check box status an asp in a gridview in asp webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

i have a gridview in a asp.net webform and i add it a check box column like this (the dataTable first column(0) is empty in sql data source and i add check boxes on the column cells):

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (rowNum != 0)//except first row
            {
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                cb.Enabled = true;
                e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(cb);//row[0]=first clmn-and this event happend for all rows

            }
            rowNum++;
        }
```

now i have a dynamic check box column! and user should check some of them and click the submit then i need the row number of the checked check boxes.
how can i do this?
i tried this before:

```
DataTable editTable = new DataTable();
editTable.Rows.Add(GridView1.Rows[0]);
var x = editTable.Rows[0][0];
```

but the x cannot get the check box true or false! it seems that getting me the original field under the check box content.

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating the controls dynamically which in most cases results in a lot of trouble, you could add the CheckBoxes in one or more template columns. The following sample shows how to add a checkbox in a template column and how to retrieve the value afterwards:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chb" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenId" runat="server" 
                    Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In my sample, I've bound some data to the GridView:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var dt = GetData();
        gridView.DataSource = dt;
        gridView.DataBind();
    }
}

private DataTable GetData()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Text", typeof(string));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { i, "Test text " + i.ToString() });
    return dt;
}
```

If you need to set the value, you can do so in the `RowDatabound` event. The following code shows how to retrieve the value of the Checkbox controls:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> checkedIds = new List<int>();
    foreach(GridViewRow row in gridView.Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>()
        .Where(x => x.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))
    {
        var hiddenId = (HiddenField)row.Cells[0].FindControl("hiddenId");
        var checkBox = (CheckBox) row.Cells[0].FindControl("chb");
        if (checkBox.Checked)
            checkedIds.Add(int.Parse(hiddenId.Value));
    }
}
```

Comment: the second part of your code doesn't work! i mean the list is empty. i traced the code and the condition never is true!

Comment: @user3125076: sorry to hear that it doesn't work; there was a problem with the code because the id column was not visible. I've fixed that by adding a hidden field and updated the answer. I've also added some more details and hope that this helps in integrating the code into your solution.